# Tunnelblick OpenVPN client on x64 Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, mac-osx, openvpn

Apparantly the Tunnelblick OpenVPN client doesn't work on x64 Snow Leopard.  Does anyone have a workaround or know of a timeline when it will be updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the nine bucks to spare, [Viscosity](http://www.viscosityvpn.com/) is superior in *any* way. It does even import your old Tunnelblick connections.